# recursive function that checks if there are k words that they "charecter equale" to a given word

Tags: java, recursion

> we will say that two words are "charecter equale" if both of them has the same charecter, for example: `baac` and `abac` are charecter equale, I am trying to write a **recursive** function that gets a *string s, a word w and integer k*, that checks if there are exactliy k words in the string that they charecter equale to the word, for example: the function should return `true` for the word `abac` , the string `aabc abdca caba xyz ab` and the number `k=2`.

Ineed help at the recursive part, i.e the function `searchMixed`, my idea was first the check if the string contain only on word (base case),

the general case is to call the function `searchMixed` without the first word

```
public class recursion1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        boolean result=searchMixed("abac","aabc abdca caba xyz ab",2);
        System.out.println("result: "+result);  
    }
    public static boolean searchMixed(String word, String s, int k)
    {

        if(s.indexOf(' ')==-1 && isEquale(word,s) && k==1)
            return true;

        if(s.indexOf(' ')==-1 && !isEquale(word,s) && k==1)
            return false;


        int pos=s.indexOf(' ');     
        System.out.println("index of"+ s.indexOf(' '));             
        String first_word=first_word=s.substring(0,pos);

        if(isEquale(word, first_word))
         searchMixed(word, s.substring(pos+1), k-1);
        else
         searchMixed(word, s.substring(pos+1), k);

        return false;
    }
```

.

```
    //this function works fine, the function checks if two words are charecter equale
    public static boolean isEquale(String word, String sub_string)
    {
        if(word.length()!=sub_string.length())
            return false;


        char[] s33=new char[sub_string.length()];
        char[] sww=new char[word.length()];


        for(int i=0;i<sub_string.length();i++)
            s33[i]=sub_string.charAt(i);        
        for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
            sww[i]=word.charAt(i);


        for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<sub_string.length();j++)
            {
            if(sww[i]==s33[j])
                s33[j]='@';     
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<sub_string.length();i++)
            if(s33[i]!='@')
                return false;

        return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: A more simpler solution. 1) Split the string by setting `" "` delimiter.  2) For each element of splited array, Check if it has same characters as word( You can do it with the help of hashing) 3) If it is same increment the count. 4)At last compare count and k and return the value accordingly.

Comment: @Error404 Stackoverflow is just like that nowadays. High rep-users keep downvoting questions they feel are simple, without actually offering constructive criticism.

Comment: Also, why did you remove the 'marked helpful by the user' tag? Did my method not work?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder do you agree with the downvotes?

Comment: @Error404 Never. I feel that if High-reputation users dislike a question for being too easy, they should at least direct us to a good site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
YourString = YourString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
String[] words = YourString.split(" ");
```

... to split the words.

```
static int n = 0;
static String keyword = "aabc";
static String[] words = null;
public static void main()
{
    n = 0;
    // Let's assume you accept 'k' here.
    String YourString = "aabc baca hjfg gabac";
    words = YourString.split(" ");
    rec(words[0]);
    if (k <= n)
        System.out.println(true);
    else
        System.out.println(false);
}
static int pos = 0;
public static void rec(String word)
{
    boolean flag = true;

    word += " ";

    if(word.length() != keyword.length() + 1)
    {
        flag = false;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < keyword.length() && flag; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++)
        {
            if(word.charAt(j) == keyword.charAt(i))
            {
                word = word.substring(0, j) + word.substring(j+1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(word.equals(" "))
        {
            n++;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(pos + 1 != words.length)
    {
        rec(words[++pos]);
    }
}
```

Now, let me explain:

1. In the recursive method `rec(String word)`, a space is added to it at the end of the word being checked (so that `substring(j+1)` does not go out of bounds)
2. If the keyword and the checked word are of different lengths, it stops checking, and moves on to '5'.
3. If the two words are of same lengths, the loop removes a single similar character from the word (That's what `word = word.substring(0, j) + word.substring(j+1);` does).
4. At the end of the loop, if all that is remaining of the word is a space, then the counter `n` increases by 1 and the loop exits.
5. If there is more than or equal to one more Strings in the array, position of the word being checked in the array increases by 1, and the next word in the array is passed to the `rec(String word)` method.

Comment: I can edit it. When should it return true and false?

Comment: @Error404 Ah, so return `true` if all words in the string are character equal to the given word, right?

Comment: Not all of them, only `k` times if so return true @Coffeehouse Coder

Comment: @Error404 I'm sorry, I'm not understanding, so the user or programmer will input `n`, right? Where `n` is the number of character equals required, after which it will return true.

Comment: `public static boolean searchMixed(String word, String s, int k)`, the function gets a number k. and should tell if there are `k` words in the string `s` that those words are character equal the the 'word', for example: for the call 'searchMixed("ab","cd kjlkjkl  ba", 3) should return false because 'k' equal to 3 and there is only one word in the given string that it character equal to the given word 'ab'

Comment: @Error404 You can keep `k` as a local variable in `main` itself. There's no need to pass it into the recursive method. The recursive method just increments `n` here, and you can later check if the character equals are more or equal to `k`.

Comment: Never mind I solved it alaready, thank you anyway, Do you know why my post got two downvotes?